# xhr files getting cancelled/failed

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube, buffering

When I try to surf to youtube.com and watch some videos , the video stuck at the beggening for 5-10 seconds trying to buffer . This is happening for both chrome and firefox .. 
When I clicked f12 > Network tab I saw this :
[image]

Also this from firefox:
[image]

xhr videoplayback files getting calncelled ..
What might be the cause of this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed , the problem was in the remote ISP as they was blocking out WAN IP address pool .
After mailing them and explaining our network default behaviour they whitelisted our IP pool